# Sass doesn't work properly in ionic

Tags: css, sass, ionic-framework

Maybe it's too hard for me to understand, but after setting Sass using [all methods](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html) it still doesn't work. I mean there are no errors in the terminal (except`[gulp-sass] file to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome-sprockets`). Just bare html-layout without any styles.

I feel the answer is terribly easy, but I cannot come up with any ideas yet.

Comment: we would have to look at how you are importing the sass libs on your project and where did you installed `font-awesome-sprockets` to answer to your question.

Comment: @Claudiordgz There is .scss file on the root: ionic.app.scs in which I import sass from libs, Then if I understand right it all compiles into ionic.app.css, which I connect through link tag. Maybe the problem is in compilation?